# Copy snapshot files from Publisher, Paste and Apply on subscriber in SQL Merge Replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, merge-replication

I read an excellent article about copying the snapshot files for Transactional replication from Publisher to Subscriber and Apply them on subscriber.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/repltalk/archive/2010/03/07/tips-to-improve-performance-when-applying-snapshot-in-transactional-replication.aspx

But the focus of this article is directed to Transactional Replication.

I want to know how we can copy the snapshots from publisher, paste them on the subscriber and apply them on subscriber. I am using Merge Replication with push subscriber, Distributor and Publisher are on the same server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - With Merge we can copy the snapshot files to the Subscriber and apply the snapshot locally using the [Merge Agent **-AltSnapshotFolder** parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147839.aspx).

Comment: I really appreciate this answer, but can you please elaborate a bit the steps that should be followed to apply snapshot locally in a merge replication?

Comment: The steps are:  1)  Generate the snapshot on the Publisher.  2)  Copy the snapshot folder to the Subscriber.  3)  Start the Merge Agent using the -AltSnapshotFolder parameter specifying the path to the local snapshot.

Comment: Here is the perfect answer - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreplication/thread/d27ace11-a891-4000-8698-25044685bf3f?prof=required